# Django How to use ManyRelatedManager

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, manyrelatedmanager

I have 2 apps that are distinct and **have no particular reason to talk to each other**.
This means I don't want to import either name in either app. All the work should be 
within a glue app.

I would like to write a glue app that would join to particular models via a ManyToManyField like:

In app customers,

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ...
```

In app pizzas,

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    ...
```

Then I would like to write the pizza-selling app that would go like this:

```
class PizzaSold(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(related_name='pizzas')
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(related_name='customers')

    objects = ManyRelatedManager()
```

so I can access pizzas from customers directly

```
 pizza = Pizza.objects.all()[0]
 for customer in pizza.customers:
     #Do something cool
```

and customers from pizza within this new app.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Where did you find out this ManyRelatedManager? Where do you import it from?

Answer (score 4):

What if you used [ManyToManyField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to model pizzas sold inside Customer model?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   pizzas_bought = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza)
```

Also, if you wish to add extra data to your customer -> pizza relations, specify the mapping Class with [through parameter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   pizzas_bought = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, through=PizzaSold)

class PizzaSold(models.Model):
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
   pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
```

Simlarly, using `related_name` should work just fine with `ManyToManyFields` as well. For instance:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   pizzas_bought = models.ManyToManyField(related_name='pizzas')
```

Comment: +1 for point to ManyToManyfield with "through" parameter. That seems to be the standard approach.

Comment: Ok, I might not have been specific, I don't want / cannot use the name pizza in the customer app, which is why I don't want / cannot use this standard approach. I might have to resort to it...

Comment: You mean you cannot use the class "Pizza"? Then why cannot you use related_name='pizzas' instead?

Comment: Hm related_name sort of works, but it's still not as convenient as ManyToManyField which automatically joins the tables. I could do it manually of course.

Comment: Why not use pizzas_bought = models.ManyToManyField(related_name='pizzas') inside Customer class?

Comment: Because that means that customer_app now depends on pizza_app, which I don't want.

Comment: How about doing it other way around:

class Pizza(models.Model):
   buyers = models.ManyToManyField(related_name='customers')

Comment: Same problem, I don't really think pizza_app should depend on customer_app. That's the solution I am implementing right now, but it feels wrong

Comment: I see. I have to ask the obvious: why you need to keep pizza and customer models in separate apps if they are so tightly coupled?

Comment: It looks like you have typos in the PIzzaSold class definition. The ForeignKeys should be the other way around.